# Insert ErrorA network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I got a error while i upload my application on server and it works fine at my localhost.
On server when doing any entry i got the following error.

Insert ErrorA network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

and with same connection string i m using it on my localhost.
my connection string is look like

```
 string connection = "Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; Initial Catalog=abcdefgh; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=ag_packers; Password=agpackers";
```

and when i used the same connection string in my local host it works fine and at server it gives the following error.

Comment: The clue really is in the error. Check it has remote connections enabled. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: it works fine on my localmachine but when i upload all the application on server/hosting it gives the above error.

Answer (score 0):

This could have different reasons, heres allready 2:

- DataSource incorrect, if it's on the same machine try: ./SqlServerName
- Your SqlServer service is not running, enable it at services.svc

Comment: My database is not on the same machine it's working fine on localhost but when i upload my whole application on server it gives the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Some points for you to check

1. Check whether your database server name/IP address is reachable from your web server by using [ping](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/ping-command.htm) dos command.
2. Check whether your target database is a `Defaule SQL Server Instance` or a `Named instance`. If it a named instance use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595073/sql-connection-string-to-named-instance) format for that.
3. Enable the [named pipes/TCP IP](http://download.pro.parallels.com/10.3.1/docs/windows/Guides/pcpw_upgrade_guide/7351.htm) for SQL server using server configuration manager.

Good luck.